# How can I make snakefile rule append the results to the input file of the rule file?

Tags: python, pipeline, snakemake

I am building a snakmake pipeline, in the final rule i have an existing files that i want the snakefile to append to:

Here is the rule:

```
rule Amend: 
    input:
        Genome_stats = expand("global_temp_workspace/result/{sample}.Genome.stats.tsv", sample= sampleID),
        GenomeSNV = expand("global_temp_workspace/result/{sample}.Genome.SNVs.tsv", sample= sampleID),
        GenomesConsensus = expand("global_temp_workspace/analysis/{sample}.renamed.consensus.fasta", sample= sampleID),
    output: 
        Genome_stats="global_temp_workspace/result/Genome.stats.tsv",
        GenomeSNV="global_temp_workspace/result/Genome.SNVs.tsv",
        GenomesConsensus="global_temp_workspace/result/Genomes.consensus.fasta"
    threads: workflow.cores
    shell: 
        """
        cat {input.Genome_stats} | tail -n +2 >> {output.Genome_stats} ;\ 
        cat {input.GenomesConsensus} >>  {output.GenomesConsensus} ;\ 
        cat {input.GenomeSNV} | tail -n +2 >> {output.GenomeSNV} ;\ 
        """
```

how can i solve it?

Thank you

I tried to do the dynamic() in the output and adding the  `touch {output.Genome_stats} {output.GenomesConsensus} {output.GenomeSNV}` at the end of the shell. but did not work.

whenevr i run the snakemake i get:

```
$ time snakemake --snakefile  V2.5.smk  --cores all 
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done.
Complete log: .snakemake/log/2023-02-15T123050.937009.snakemake.log

real    0m1.022s
user    0m2.744s
sys     0m2.797s
```

Comment: I tried to replace the  {output.Genome_stats} in the shell with the path of the file and removing the output section. But, this affected the end rule

Comment: I don't think this is possible, or if it's possible it's a bad hack that's not idiomatic, am anti-pattern. Instead of appending, you should create a new file that is the original plus what you want to append.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is not idempotent and is usually a recipe for trouble. What happens if the machine breaks down or the process is killed during the write stage? What happens if a rule is accidentally ran twice?

As advised by @Cornelius Roemer in the comment to the question, the safer way is to write to a new file. If the overwrite-like behaviour is desired, then the new file can be moved to the original file location, but some record/checkpoint file should be created to make sure that Snakemake knows not to re-process the file.